# SSRS detail cell empty when same value as the one above

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created an SSRS 2008 report containing 3 groups and a single detail line. Everything works correctly except when a value in the detail line is equal to the one in the detail line above in which case it is blank. All of the group totals are correct in that they include all values including the ones that are not showing up. I have tried modifying the report by replacing all of the cell expressions with =Fields!Bal0.Value + Rnd(). When I do this all of the values appear since (I assume) they are no longer equal to the value above.
Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light on my problem.

Comment: It sounds like you might have the SuppressDuplicates of the column set to true.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS text boxes have a hide duplicates attribute. In my case it was set to the name of the dataset. I changed it to "None" and this fixed the problem.